# Loading a series of positionally defined file records into a class

Tags: objective-c, class, file, nsmutablearray

As you will be able to see shortly, I'm pretty new to objective-c and need a little help.

I'm attempting to read a file that has a series of fixed length records on it (downloaded from a mainframe) and load each entry into a class instance and then add that class instance into an array.  Let's call that class CLASS_A.  I have a second class, CLASS_B which I have wrapped around the input file which has one method to read the file into a NSString, a second method advances to the next record in the file (moves a pointer just past the next '\n') and other methods are used to extract individual data fields into returned NSString values.  There are also some other imbedded checks to make sure that each field fetch does not reach beyond the current record.  Probably a bit fussy but since this is a demonstration program, I don't care much.

I declared several instances of CLASS_A and loaded each instance of CLASS_A using the methods defined for CLASS_B and then loaded these CLASS_A instances into an array successfully.  Fine.  I can see them in the debugger and can fetch them using the various array methods which do that.

Now I want to generalize this thing so I can set up a loop and just merrily fill up CLASS_A table with one CLASS_A entry per input file record accessed via the various methods in CLASS_B until I run out of input records.  In my working example I explicitly named about 5 or so CLASS_A instances and added them into the array.  How do I get away from explicitly naming the CLASS_A instances and just loop around.  I really don't care what the names of the individual CLASS_A instances are... they exist to be bundled into the table and fetched out as required by other parts of the program.

Any help would be great.  The code is a bit longish for this site  but if it is helpful I can post it as well.

Answer (score 0):

A classic way to do this is to have a class method (the ones which start with a +) which takes in the data, and hands over a populated instance.

```
+ (CLASS_A *) class_aFromStringArray: (NSArray *)stringArray {
   CLASS_A *myInstance = [[CLASS_A alloc] init];

   //Populate myInstance ivars here from stringArray

   [myInstance autorelease];
   return myInstance;
}
```

In your other class, you'd have your loop do something like

```
   while (FileNotEOF) {
     peel off a line;
     parse line into (NSMutableArray *) aMutableArray;
     [myClass_AArray addObject: [CLASS_A class_aFromStringArray: aMutableArray]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that... when I get a chance later this week I'll give it a try.  Seems pretty clean.

Comment: Just as a follow on, I want to make sure I totally understand this.  It seems that by using the class method directly in the addObject method, you away from having to name the instance.  While I get it and it is clearly the way to go, it just seems like sort of a coding trick to me.

Comment: A formal way to think of it is as an anonymous object. Just as a variable name is a way to refer to it, a position in an array is a way to refer to it. Instead of MyClass_A1, you have (sort of) MyClass_A[1].  (Of course, really you'd have [myClass_A objectAtIndex: 1], but you get the idea.)

Comment: If you haven't, BTW, make sure you look at "Fast Enumeration". It'll be the next thing you want.

Comment: was going to continue asking on this one but thought better of it and am typing this over the original comment.

Comment: This may be a really stupid question but I'm going with it.... I coded up the example and for some reason I can not reference this new setter method from within the main program.  It compiles but I get the following:                                                unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001113f0: I am probably defining this thing incorrectly in the @interface for the class.

Comment: Nevermind... I got it... I had set up my (id) stuff wrong and compounded by me mis-capitalizing a method name.  It works fine now.  Thanks for your help.